# Is it possible to remove a fragment without replacing it by another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, preferencefragment

I use an ActionBarActivity with NavigationDrawer and a ListView in the content frame of Drawer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyt_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_notes"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"       >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_frame"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/darkGray"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
     </FrameLayout>
```

I open PreferenceFragment from one of Drawer items like this:

```
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                PrefsFragment prefs = new PrefsFragment();
                transaction.add(R.id.content_frame, prefs);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
```

and this is my PrefsFragment:

```
public class PrefsFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, new PrefsFr())
            .commit();
}


public class PrefsFr extends PreferenceFragment {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);          
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
      ...  }
}

}
```

but I can not remove this fragment.
When I toggle to another Drawer item; PreferenceFragment remains on top of ListView in content_frame  with tranceparent background.

Is it possible in ActionBarActivity to remove a fragment without replacing it by another fragment ?
If not so how to use PreferenceFragment for api > 11 ? Is it true that the only way is to replace fragments with each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible in ActionBarActivity to remove a fragment without replacing it by another fragment ?

Yes, you can use [`FragmentTransaction#remove(Fragment)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#remove(android.app.Fragment))

The underlying problem however is that you are showing the PreferenceFragment with `transaction.add(R.id.content_frame, prefs);`. If you want only the PreferenceFragment to display wihthout the ListView behind it, you should use `replace()` instead.

Comment: Sorry I tested replace() and remove() with no success. I do not know what is wrong!

Comment: I saved "prefs" as a static field and then removed it this way : transaction.remove(prefs);
transaction.commit();
      Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that would be one way to remove that Fragment from the FragmentManager.

Comment: Thank you @Tanis.7x , I found my problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22474821/3569123) I have to call replace with a TAG in onActivityCreated method of PrefsFragment and use getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG) in main activity to remove it.