# Setting FragmentStatePagerAdapter count to 0 does not destroy any current visible fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a PagerAdapter with a dynamic number of elements. You can modify the number of tabs with a single call, which clears the list and the count to 0. Unfortunately, this does not remove the fragment that is currently showing.

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<Pojo> pojos = new ArrayList<>;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pojos.size();
    }  

    public void removeAll() {
        this.pojos.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to force the ViewPager to clear himself?

**UPDATE 1:**

If you use `viewPager.removeAllViews()` then the viewPager is unusable afterwards even after adapter notifies new data changes.

Comment: Question is asked many times. Try this one for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849552/update-viewpager-dynamically/17855730#17855730

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474584/remove-old-fragment-from-fragment-manager

Comment: @CharefEddineMechalikh not even close.

Comment: @Michal Seems legit. Thank you.