# How to delete a Tab and its associated fragment from TabLayout & FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-tablayout, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am trying to create a program with TabLayout and an option menu which when selected can add or delete the tab along with the fragment. I can delete the tab but I am not able to understand what else needs to be done because I have to delete the fragments that the tab holds, more over I may also have to rearrange the position of the fragments which I just can't seem to figure out. Could you please help me with this ?

under mainAcitivity this is how I add tabs

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        tab1= tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB 1");
        tabLayout.addTab(tab1);

        tab2 = tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB 2");
        tabLayout.addTab(tabKantipur);
```

This is the FragmentstatePagerAdapter

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    int tabCount;

    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numberOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.tabCount = numberOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
              return NewsFragment.newInstance("data for fragment 1");
            case 1:
               return NewsFragment.newInstance("data for fragment 2");
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabCount;
    }
}
```

Basically here NewsFragment is the fragment whose new instance is used in the tabs. Under onActivityResult I am getting the data that has been requested from the options Menu to add or delete fragmetns

```
 mpagerAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
removedTab = ..data received from ooption menu
// here I want to remove the Tab & the fragments (tab1 & its fragment)


if (removeTab == "tab1") {
  tabLayout.removeTab(tab1);
  mpagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

As I do this only the first tab gets removed  I would like to know how to remove  the associated fragment too.

Comment: You want to do that in the same step? Not sure, but you can always programmatically remove the Fragment.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474584/remove-old-fragment-from-fragment-manager

Comment: Also, `removeTab == "tab1"` is not how you compare strings in Java

Comment: Yes I want to do it in the same step I have spent weeks still can't do it. All tutorials talk about setting tag to the fragment but as you can see I don't have Tag in my fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had asked a similar question using fragmentarray for which i got it to work . this is the link, [Issue: Logic to find the position of a fragment in a fragment arraylist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994423/issue-logic-to-find-the-position-of-a-fragment-in-a-fragment-arraylist)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to explicitly delete the fragment, you can remove the fragment.

You can remove the tab and do notifyDataSetChanged on the viewPagerAdapter instance.It will take care of removing the fragment.

Comment: I am already using it but it doesn't remove the fragment. please check the code above.   mpagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: you also have to modify the tabCount variable and then do notifyDataSetChangesd().