# Android: how to end a fragment when transit to another?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

Considering I have a navigation view and few fragments associated with it. I wanted to end the fragment when transited to another

For example if Im in fragment A and I click fragment B (or any), The fragment A should get closed or destroyed.

Note: `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);` doesn't work

code for transaction

```
if(fragment!=null){
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fl, fragment);
            ft.commit();

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove old Fragment from fragment manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474584/remove-old-fragment-from-fragment-manager). You should also ensure you are calling `commit()` on your transaction.

Comment: @ChrisStillwell they are using replace which isn't working, consider me playing a video in the 1st fragment and when I switch to 2nd the sound still plays in the background. And yes I have added commit()

Comment: Ah I see now. Are you using VideoView? If so, call `stopPlayback();` in your Fragment's `onPause()` or `onStop()` callback.

Comment: @ChrisStillwell hmm no. I'm using webview in which there is YouTube video

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, you're WebView isn't getting unloaded when your Fragment transitions. To resolve this, call `webView.stopLoading();` and `webView.destroy();` from either the Fragment's `onPause()` or `onStop()` callback. you may also want to wrap both of those calls in a null check just in case webView actually does unload. So your code block will look something like this:

```
if(webView != null){
    webView.stopLoading();
    webView.destroy();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I found a new method by trail and error, I'm deleting the fragment stack - 1 before committing

Answer (score 0):

that's easy and handling automatically from android side , just enough after to replace your fragment don't do **`.addToBackStack(null)`** and when you go to next fragment , last fragment gone

Comment: @ArdalanSajediI have added.

Comment: this code is true and should work correctly  why you say it doesn't work

Comment: when I play the video (from YouTube in a webview) and later when I change/switch the fragment (present in navigation) the audio plays in the background.

Comment: also it was fine if I back press and go back to the same fragment but the problem is that the fragment reloads

Comment: thats another problem you have two ways 
first you can use onResume method and write your code when you go to second fragment the video or audio will be stop 
and  use first method to dont come back to web view fragment

Comment: second way is :
set tag to your web view when you creat at first and after go to another fragment with thats tag remove web view fragment

Comment: for first way or second ?

Comment: It would help me a lot  if you could send for both

Comment: @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mWebView.onPause();
}
use this to the webview fragment and instead of mWebView use name of your webView 
and for second way 
use this 
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT);
if(fragment != null)
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();