# Ram usage increases after replacing fragment android

Tags: java, android

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = null;
Fragment fragment = null;
fragment = HomePlaceholder.getFragment(position);
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment).commit();
```

Ram usage increases after replacing fragment android

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what your code is doing?

Comment: When Application start i am adding First fragment that time allocation of heap is 68MB. After that I replace first fragment with second then  allocation of heap 90MB its get increases continuously after adding other fragments

Comment: [Can you remove](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474584) the first fragment before you add the second fragment?

Comment: Yes, I also removed first fragment and the add other One but same thing is happen